# Multiple requests at same instance of time, rails unable to handle update of array column type

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5

I am getting multiple requests to an endpoint from front end. 
For eg- Front end uploads 10 images to Google cloud and whenever the front end gets response from google cloud, they make an API call to backend for storing the asset record in db. In database the asset_ids are being stored in a column named `asset_ids` of array type . Now the problem is, out of 10 images some of the images are not getting saved in the array column.
Some of the requests are trying to override the previous data in the array column.

Note:- When i tried with optimistic locking, i am getting the exception as `ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError` . So, what will be the idle approach to resolve the issue .

Below is the endpoint which handles the requests .

```
def upload_assets
    gcs = GoogleCloud::StoreAssetDetail.new(file_upload_params, current_user: current_user)
    if gcs.process
      @gallery.asset_ids << gcs.asset_id
      @gallery.name = gallery_params[:name] if gallery_params[:name].present?
      if @gallery.save
        asset = Asset.find(gcs.asset_id)
        render json: { asset_id: asset.id, imgix_url: asset.decorate.imgix_cdn }, status: :created
      else
        respond_with_error(@gallery.errors.full_messages.join(', '), :unprocessable_entity, @gallery.errors)
      end
    else
      respond_with_error(gcs.errors.full_messages.join(', '), :unprocessable_entity, gcs.errors)
    end
  rescue ActiveRecord::StaleObjectError
    puts "Error while uploading"
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution for the problem which i was facing. The cause of the issue was multiple requests trying to update the same record at same time. So, went through the rails documentation about stale objects and went ahead with the **Pessimistic** locking approach. In Pessimistic locking the object is locked and barred even to be read by other request unless the lock is released ( in my case lock is released when the record gets saved ). Hence, this approach got my issue resolved.